# Implementing my own DBGrid

Tags: delphi, components, tdbgrid

I want to implement my own DBGrid my problem is that i don't know much about components how can i override the onkeydown event ?

A tutorial on extending the functionality of components would be great.

Comment: From your question I infer you are a beginner in this matter. You shouldn't start by writing a grid component; it is insanely complex.

Comment: I just want to extend the functionality with a basic thing like incremental search if i override the KeyDown method it will be enough i guess...

Comment: Head [here](http://www.delphidabbler.com/tips/83) for an `Implemention of an incremental search capability` with a TComboBox sample, and [here](http://cc.embarcadero.com/item/27541) for the TDBGrid one.

Answer (score 3):

You don't override events, but methods that fire them. The `OnKeyDown` event is fired by [KeyDown](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/XE2/en/Controls.TWinControl.KeyDown) method which in turn is called by [DoKeyDown](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Controls.TWinControl.DoKeyDown) method (triggered by the WM_KEYDOWN message). So one of those is the method you have to override in your custom control, depending at which stage you want to intercept the keypress.

BTW there is an exellent article by Peter Below on the internals of how VCL key message processing works: [A Key's Odyssey](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/38447). Make sure you read that as well.

Comment: Thanks for your answer if you could post a simple example or an article about extending the functionality of components would be great.

Comment: Search for the pdf version of `Delphi 7 for Windows Component Writer's Guide` on the internet.

Comment: The topic is too big and complicated for a simple example... just google for `custom delphi component` and plenty of useful stuff should turn up, the first links seem pretty good: http://delphi.about.com/od/vclusing/a/customvcldev.htm and http://delphi.about.com/library/bluc/text/uc080701a.htm